# A basic birthday probability question

Tags: probability

**The problem:** Suppose the members of a family of 3 were either born on Saturday or Sunday. What are the chances of this family having birthday parties on both Saturday and Sunday?

**First approach (from the textbook):**

With $x_{i}$ as the number of birthdays on the day $i$:

$n(S)=\binom{4}{3}=4$, as the number of the solutions of $x_{1}+x_{2}=3, x\geqslant0$.

$n(A)=\binom{2}{1}=2$, as the number of the solutions of $x_{1}+x_{2}=3, x\geqslant1$.

Thus $P(E)=\frac{n(A)}{n(S)}=\frac{1}{2}.$

**Second approach (mine):**

Since the events are independent, the chances of all 3 being born on Saturday would be $(\frac{1}{2})^3$, same with Sunday. So the chances of having birthdays on both days would be $1-2\times \frac{1}{8}=\frac{3}{4}$.

---

So which one of these approaches are correct? And what is the reason of the other giving the wrong result?

Comment: We don't know, because a crucial piece of information is missing.  The natural assumption, given the presentation of the problem, is that each family member is born on Saturday or Sunday with equal and independent probability.  That would make your solution correct.  But the problem as written doesn't actually say that.  There are other potential probability distributions that make the textbook's answer correct.

Comment: "*Thus $P(E)=\dfrac{n(A)}{n(S)}=\dots$*"  No! No! No!!!  The probability of a discrete event in a finite sample space being equal to the size of the event divided by the size of the sample space is valid as a calculation **only if** the outcomes in the sample space are known to be equally likely to occur.  If you don't know this then you may **not** use that calculation method.  There are two outcomes to playing the lottery, you either win or you lose.  Half of the outcomes are you winning.  You don't win half of the time however.

Comment: What textbook is this?

Comment: @NeatMath It's a local (yet widely used) book on "probability and statistics for engineering", so I doubt knowing the title would be of any use.

Comment: The textbook solution is nonsense. No reasonable assumption will make it work.

Comment: "*For engineering*"  That makes more sense why such a beginner mistake would have occurred... If you have the opportunity, use an entirely different book... either instead of or at least in addition to the assigned book.

Comment: @NeatMath If we were to assume that each quantity of saturdays (*0,1,2, or 3*) were equally likely to have occurred, then we'd arrive at that answer... however almost no natural processes actually follow such a distribution.  I agree, it is not a reasonable assumption at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course we assume that any given person is equally likely to be born on Saturday as Sunday, particularly given that no other explicit statement to the contrary is given.  This is the so-called "non-informative" prior, based on the "principle of indifference."  Also, *on average* there are as many Saturdays as Sundays within a year.  (As "meta-reasoning," I would point to the fact that the OP has a reputation of $31$, and so would likely have made this assumption but not voiced it explicitly.)

The second is correct.  Person $A$ is on one of the weekend days.  Call it Saturday (without loss of generality).  What is the probability that at either $B$ or $C$ (or both) are on Sunday?  Well, it is 1 minus the probability both are on Saturday, i.e., $1 - (1/2)^2 = 3/4$.

Another way:  What is the probability all three are on Saturday?  $(1/2)^3$. What is the probability all three are on Sunday?  $(1/2)^3$.  So what is the probability all three on *one* same day?  $1/8 + 1/8 =1/4$.  What is the probability they are *not* all on the same day?  $1 - 1/4 = 3/4$.

Comment: You're making the natural **but unstated** assumption that each family member was born with equal and independent probability on either of the two days.  You should probably make that assumption explicit in your answer.

Comment: The second is correct $*~~~~~~~~~~$($*$given the natural assumptions of uniformity and independence which are missing from the problem statement)